# How To Create a Fluid Grid Style Layout?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know how to setup a masonry layout but what I can't figure out is how to have each item be a different size like the screenshot below.

How do I achieve that?

http://www.sitebuildertips.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Fluid-Grid.png

Comment: Check out this tool. [960 grid system](http://960.gs).
It allows you to create a custom fluid grid. <br/> `Take a look at this` [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UXjnF/) `to understand how it works.`

Comment: Did you achieve that sort of layout with masonry ?

Comment: I think this article might help you. It helped me a lot. [Responsive masonry](http://osvaldas.info/responsive-jquery-masonry-or-pinterest-style-layout)

Comment: I actually figured out a way to do it by using jQuery to add a unique numeric ID to each element then using CSS to apply different sizes to each element. Now all I need to do is figure out how to make that work this infinite scroll.